# Выключить checked для radio button при повторном нажатии

Tags: javascript, html

В `HTML` можно только включить `checked` у `radio button`, а выключить его при повторном нажатии на тот же `radio` нельзя.
Как осуществить выключение `checked` при повторном нажатие на тот же `radio` методами на `JavaScript`?

Comment: Вы имели в виду радиобаттон?

Comment: да, исправил вопрос)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function clickRadio(el) {
  var siblings = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio'][name='" + el.name + "']");
  for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
    if (siblings[i] != el)
      siblings[i].oldChecked = false;
  }
  if (el.oldChecked)
    el.checked = false;
  el.oldChecked = el.checked;
}
```

```html
<label>Radiobutton 1 <input type="radio" onclick="clickRadio(this)" name="radio" /></label>
<label>Radiobutton 2 <input type="radio" onclick="clickRadio(this)" name="radio" /></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно сделать через изменяемый счет.

```
let checkbox = document.querySelector(".open-close")
let count = 0


function vision() {
  if (checkbox.checked === true) {
    if (count === 1) {
        checkbox.checked = false
        count = 0
    } else {
        count += 1
    }
  }
}
checkbox.addEventListener('click', vision)
```